# Asp.Net - Master Page - How to avoid unneccesary calls

Tags: asp.net

I have one question to ask about Asp.Net Master page.
In the master page and page load event i have code like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
     if (Session["UserName"] != null && Session["UserLastName"] != null)
     {
         lblDisplayName.Text = Session["UserName"].ToString() + " " + Session["UserLastName"].ToString() ;
     }
   }
}
```

Master page is applied for Page 1 and Page 2.
Whenever i redirect from Page 1 to Page 2 or Page 2 to Page 1. It executes page load of Master Page. And above code executes each and every time. Is it not possible to set the User Name just one time.

Is there anything so that these could be avoided?

Thanks,
Mahesh.

Comment: I think you're over-estimating the amount of load those 3 lines of code are placing on the server...

Comment: I wonder if OP knows how much code is executed until Page_Load and how another big "much" is after.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is stateless because the HTTP protocol is stateless; therefore, the master page instance in page 1 knows nothing of the request made for page 2.  So you have to re-establish the label every time on page load.

If you are asking about this in relation to performance, I wouldn't worry about setting the label every time.  The biggest issue with performance tends to be:

1. Large page sizes which take a long time to download on the client.
2. Inefficient database queries.
3. There are others, but that's a topic of another discussion.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a stateless protocol.

When transferring from one page to another, you are losing all state information.  Indeed, much of web development centers on providing some semblance of state in a stateless protocol.

We achieve this by pulling values from somewhere - cookies, or as in your case, the Session.

In short, when your page loads it knows nothing about the page that has gone before.  Accordingly, you'll need to check for and set the user each time.